# Correlation function for matching dates within a range of data

Tags: excel, function

I have a spreadsheet with four columns where columns B and D contain counts of cars using various roads, taken in the last 30 days. A macro has processed the data in these ranges and changed the outlier values to "Bad" so the following correlation formula ignores them:

```
{=IFERROR(CORREL(IF(B4:B33<>"Bad";IF(D4:D33<>"Bad";B4:B33));IF(B4:B33<>"Bad";IF(D4:D33<>"Bad";D4:D33)));"0")}
```

Columns A and C contain the dates that the counts were taken on. Unfortunately, sometimes these dates aren't the same, no data available on Christmas in some areas, Boxing Day in others etc. Obviously this destroys the correlation, as it puts the dates out of synchronization and the correlation falls apart.

Is there any way I can adapt the formula for it to check to see if the dates are the same before correlating? It'd almost be like a `vlookup`, find the date, if match, add to calculation, if not then go to the next date. I'm happy for it to only correlate 26 of the 30 days if there are that many conflicts.

For example, for the last six days performed on the 28th of December, looking at six calendar days up to but not including the 28th:

```
        A         B        C         D
    22/12/2012    9    22/12/2012   Bad
    23/12/2012   10    23/12/2012   22
    24/12/2012    3    24/12/2012   21
    25/12/2012    7    26/12/2012   18
    26/12/2012    8    27/12/2012   15
    27/12/2012   15
```

The last cells of columns C and D are blank.

I would like the formula to only correlate the four days, 23rd, 24th, 26th and 27th, matching up the appropriate counts.

Given that I'm going to be correlating this information with a number of locations, each with different reporting dates, filtering the dates before correlating and deleting unmatched dates is not a great option, but I will consider it if there is no other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this using only a single-cell array formula.

However, with the aid of a helper column, it can be done. Array-enter the following formula into the range `E4:E33`:

`{=(IF(COUNTIF(C4:C33;A4:A33);INDEX(D4:D33;MATCH(A4:A33;C4:C33;0));""))}`

This should result in the following:

```
        A         B        C         D    E
    22/12/2012    9    22/12/2012   Bad  Bad
    23/12/2012   10    23/12/2012   22   22
    24/12/2012    3    24/12/2012   21   21
    25/12/2012    7    26/12/2012   18
    26/12/2012    8    27/12/2012   15   18
    27/12/2012   15                      15
```

Now the correlation can be calculated with the non-array formula:

`=IFERROR(CORREL(B4:B13;E4:E13);0)`

**Note:** `CORREL` ignores pairs of values where either or both are *not numbers*, ie, text, logical, or empty (but not 0). Thus it is not necessary to explicitly check for and exclude "Bad" or missing values.